# using namespace does not work for definitions?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am having trouble understanding c++ namespaces. Consider the following example:

```
//distr.h

namespace bogus{
    extern const int x;
    extern const int y;
    double made_up_distr(unsigned param);
}
```

Now if I define my variables like the cpp below everything compiles fine

```
//distr.cpp

#include "distr.h"
#include <cmath>

const int bogus::x = 10;   
const int bogus::y = 100;

double bogus::made_up_distr(unsigned param){
    auto pdf = (exp(param) / bogus::x) + bogus::y;
    return pdf;
}
```

But if I try to simply bring in the `bogus` namespace and use instead

```
//broken distr.cpp

#include "distr.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace bogus;

const int x = 10;
const int y = 100;

double made_up_distr(unsigned param){
    auto pdf = (exp(param) / x) + y;
    return pdf;
}
```

My compiler tells me that the reference to `x` and `y` is ambiguous.
Why is that?

Comment: I think it is because `x` and `y` in the second case might also be a separate definition not necessarily `bogus::x` and `bogus::y`. I mean compiler thinks that you want to define a different `x` and `y`, but at the same time `bogus::x` and `bogus::y` are also visible. So it is unable to decide and emits an error.

Comment: WARNING: You must use EXTERN for both defines of const variables in C++!!! This is different from C!!!

Comment: extern const int bogus::x = 10;

Comment: @NeilKirk Not necessary in this case, because the `extern` inherits from the declaration in the namespace. (`extern const int x;`)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a simple reason why this can't plausibly work the way you expected:

```
namespace bogus {
    const int x;
}
namespace heinous {
    const int x;
}

using namespace bogus;
using namespace heinous;

const int x = 10;
```

now, should `x` above refer to `bogus::x`, `heinous::x` or a new global `::x`?
It would be the third without the `using` statements, which means here that adding a using statement would change the meaning of existing code in a particularly subtle way.

The using statement is used to introduce the contents of a scope (usually but not necessarily a namespace) for *lookup*. The statement

```
const int x = 10;
```

wouldn't normally *require* a lookup in the first place, except to detect an ODR violation.

Answer (score 1):

Name lookup for the identifier in declarations/definitions doesn't work the same way as name lookup in usage. In particular, it doesn't care about using statements. There is a very simple reason for this: if it were different, it would lead to all sorts of nasty surprises. Consider this:

```
// sneakattack.h
namespace sneakattack { void foo(); }
using namespace sneakattack;

// somefile.cpp
#include "sneakattack.h"
void foo() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }

// otherfile.cpp
void foo();
int main() { foo(); }
```

This program currently works: the declaration `sneakattack::foo` is ignored, and the definition `::foo` is correctly linked to the use in otherfile. But if name lookup worked differently, somefile would suddenly define `sneakattack::foo`, not `::foo`, and the program would fail to link.